# Multiple WHENs vs single WHEN with IN in CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, case

I'm writing a script to import from an old disorganised database to a new one, and as such I'm having to do a lot of sanity checking. The old database doesn't do much deleting, so there's a lot of data hanging around that I need to filter out too. As such, performance is a consideration.

Q: I'm wondering if there is a reason to choose having multiple condition statements returning the same result or whether having an `IN` to catch all  matching conditions. From running the SQL below the difference is 0.03s over 320,000 rows.

I believe SQL Server will create a temp table and `INNER JOIN` on it when using an IN, but I'm not sure how that overhead would perform against a simple equal match.

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN textTable.[Char] = 'A' THEN 'String'
    WHEN textTable.[Char] = 'C' THEN 'String'
    WHEN textTable.[Char] = 'E' THEN 'String'
    WHEN textTable.[Char] = '2' THEN 'Int'
    WHEN textTable.[Char] = '4' THEN 'Int'
    WHEN textTable.[Char] = '6' THEN 'Int'
END AS 'Variable'
FROM [Datatable] AS textTable

SELECT CASE
    WHEN textTable.[Char] IN ('A', 'B', 'C') THEN 'String'
    WHEN textTable.[Char] IN ('2', '4', '6') THEN 'Int'
END AS 'Variable'
FROM [Datatable] AS textTable
```

Comment: If you check the query plan between the two (press CTRL-L) I think you'll find that the second one is rewritten to the first one anyway. So no difference

Comment: What is your question again. BTW, you usually optimize the `JOIN` and `WHERE` clause, not `SELECT`.

Comment: Yes, they both look like the same plan. My question is: are they to all intents and purposes the same, or is there an under-the-hood reason that 1 is better than the others in certain circumstances/always?

Comment: 2nd is more readable and shorter.. i vote for that one.

Comment: No it's purely a coding preference. The first one certainly appears to violate DRY https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @IvanStarostin - I didn't actually need to know if it was a number, it was just an [mcve]

Comment: That is actually a confusing and disorienting example, IMO. There is no question here that can be answered specifically. Nick has already pointed it. Your assumptions about temp tables can be easily checked by running these queries and examining actual execution plans.